# Nancy decimal property binding not working

Tags: c#, nancy

I'm having problem with binding decimal property:

```
Oh noes! ---> Nancy.ModelBinding.ModelBindingException: Unable to bind to type: Nancy.Models.SomeModel
at Nancy.ModelBinding.DefaultBinder.Bind(NancyContext context, Type modelType, Object instance, BindingConfig configuration, String[] blackList)
at Nancy.ModelBinding.DynamicModelBinderAdapter.TryConvert(ConvertBinder binder, Object& result)
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
at Nancy.ModelBinding.ModuleExtensions.Bind[TModel](INancyModule module)
at KBZServisNancy.Modules.SomeModule.<.ctor>b__2(Object x) in d:\Nancy\Modules\SomeDecimalModule.cs:line 38
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Func`2 , Object )
at Nancy.Routing.Route.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(Object parameters, CancellationToken context)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Nancy.NancyEngine.InvokeOnErrorHook(NancyContext context, ErrorPipeline pipeline, Exception ex)
at Nancy.NancyEngine.InvokeOnErrorHook(NancyContext context, ErrorPipeline pipeline, Exception ex)
```

If value of decimal property is for example 20,50 binding works fine, but if value is 20.50 I get upper error message. According to this, there may be problem with culture sensitive but context culture is {en-US}. There were already some issues of this kind [Culture model binding](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/pull/871) and they are solved so I dont't have idea where the problem could be. I'm using Nancy v0.23 with self hosting in console application. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4):

In the current Nancy version just write own `ITypeConverter`

```
/// <summary>
/// Nancy converter to convert numeric types with InvariantCulture.
/// </summary>
public class NancyNumericConverter : ITypeConverter
{
    public bool CanConvertTo(Type destinationType, BindingContext context)
    {
        return destinationType.IsNumeric();
    }

    public object Convert(string input, Type destinationType, BindingContext context)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return System.Convert.ChangeType(input, destinationType, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

(I have updated the issue https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/1587 too.)

Answer (score 2):

I've raised this as an issue, looks like a culture issue, works fine when its US, but if I change my local culture to Turkey and try with a decimal point I get the exception also.

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/1587